# operator new - Why operator new allocate array with negative value

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

```
template <class T> class Signal {

    protected: int N;                                       // length of array

    public:    T *sig;
    Signal<T>  fft();
    }

    template <class T> Signal<T> Signal<T>::fft() {


        if (N==1) return *this;
        if (N%2!=0) 
            cout<<"N is not power of 2";

        else{

            Signal<T> even;
            even.sig=new T[N/2];
            Signal<T> odd;
            Signal<T> esig;
            Signal<T> osig;
            Signal<T> y;
            y.sig=new T[N];

            for (int i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
            even.sig[i]=sig[2*i];  /* I failed here because new operator allocate  array  with negative value*/
            }
            esig= even.fft();

            odd = even;
            for (int i=0;i<N/2;i++) {
                odd.sig[i]=sig[2*i+1];
            }
            osig= odd.fft();

        /*not importan part*/
            }
            return y;
        }
```

This is part of my class which represent Signal. I show only one one part of method fft which failed.

I got error Invalide allocation size 4294967295 in line where I put comment. When I debug I got that value for even.sig is 0x0062b9f8 {-842150451}.
How can I fix this and got array of not negative size.

Comment: Where do you initialize `this->sig`?

Comment: How do you get 0x0062b9f8 to be a negative value? Addresses are never negative. And it seems like you never set `N` to anything useful.

Comment: `N % 2 != 0` tests whether `N` is even or not, not whether it is a power of 2.  To test for a power of 2, you want to do something like `N & (N - 1)`. (This expression resets the low order bit.  If the number was a power of two, only one bit is set, and resetting it results in 0.)

Comment: I have constructor which initialize this.sig :

    template <class T> Signal<T>::Signal(int length){
     N=length; 
     M=1;
     sig= new T[N];
     t0=0;
     deltaT=1;
     for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
      sig[i]=t0+i*deltaT;
     }
     if  (N>60) 
      setFlag(1);
     else
      setFlag(0);
    }

Comment: I agree with you James Kanze, I didn't want to check if N is even or odd, I wanted to check if is power of 2 so I'll change that condition. But how I got value for even.sig is 0x0062b9f8 {-842150451}?